# Ошибки при передаче объекта по ссылке С++

Tags: c++, ссылки

Я сделал 2 класса
У класса есть метод в которой передается ссылка на объект. Ссылка потому что объект большой по размеру и потому что это нужно быстро делать.

```
class RayTracePack {
public:
    vector<RayTraceInfo>  intersects;
    RayTracePack() {
        intersects.resize(0);
    };
    void append(RayTraceInfo& info) {
        int i;
        if (intersects.size() == 0) {
            intersects.push_back(info);
        }
        else {
            if (info.distance > intersects.back().distance) {
                intersects.push_back(info);
            }
            else if (info.distance < intersects[0].distance) {
                intersects.insert(intersects.begin(), info);
            }
            else {
                for (i = 0; i < intersects.size() - 2; i++) {
                    if (intersects[i].distance < info.distance && intersects[i + 1].distance > info.distance) {
                        intersects.insert(intersects.begin() + i, info);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
};
class RayTraceInfo {
public:
    double shift;
    double distance;
    FlatSprite sprite;
    RayTraceInfo(double shift_, double distance_, FlatSprite& sprite_){
        shift = shift_;
        distance = distance_;
        sprite = sprite_;
    };
};
```

Я передаю туда значения вот так

```
// rays :: RayTracePack
point = vision_sprites[i].getIntersection(center, to_point);
FlatSprite sp = vision_sprites[i];
rays.append(RayTraceInfo(vision_sprites[i].getShift(point), sqrt(point.sub(center).mul(point.sub(center)).sum()), sp));
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Ошибка  C2664   "void RayTracePack::append(RayTraceInfo &)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "RayTraceInfo" в "RayTraceInfo &"
```

Visual Studio 2022 C++
Я новичок в C++ поэтому возможно еще где-то не понимаю ссылки т.д. но вроде все должно работать. Решение проблемы не нашел. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы передаете l-value

```
void append(RayTraceInfo& info)
```

но тут

```
rays.append(RayTraceInfo(...))
```

вы передаете временный объект, который по ссылке передавать нельзя.

Варианты решения —

```
void append(RayTraceInfo info)   
void append(const RayTraceInfo& info)
```

Я бы использовал второй вариант...

Еще одно решение

```
RayTraceInfo r = RayTraceInfo(...);
rays.append(r);
```

мне категорически не нравится :)

Comment: Именно такие варианты решения? В таком случае, почему не ```void append(RayTraceInfo&& info)``` и ```void append(const RayTraceInfo& info)```??? Если уж объект такой большой, то не помешает сделать rvalue вариант такого метода. Я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ввиду ограничений 2 первых методов 3 вариант я счел нормальным и он заработал.

Comment: Хотя не понятно чем 3 вариант отличается от начального?

Comment: Почитайте про move-семантику. Это может помочь оптимизировать программу. @FotonPC

Comment: Дело в том, что в C++ есть rvalue и lvalue. rvalue - временный объект, например ```1+4``` - результат будет rvalue, а ```int fooInt = 1 + 4``` - lvalue (переменная fooInt - lvalue, а 1 + 4 - rvalue). ```void append(const RayTraceInfo& info) ``` - это метод, который принимает в себя lvalue объект. ```void append(RayTraceInfo&& info) ``` - метод, который принимает в себя rvalue. @FotonPC

Comment: @FotonPC, вообще то , если эту ошибку уберете, то реализация append  вызывает  огромные сомнения....  И, в добавок, сомнение вызывает выбор контейнера, если учесть ваши намерения...

Comment: Интересно, какие ограничения вы увидели в первых вариантах?... Чем отличается? Созданием объекта, который вы можете изменять. Вы же, работая без `const`, говорите компилятору: мне потребуется изменить этот объект! И как вы его будете менять, временный? Это то же самое, что пытаться передать как `int&` просто двойку. Как вы ее измените?

Comment: Вообще - есть не только rvalue и lvalue. https://habr.com/ru/post/441742/ - вот статья про все категории.
Сразу после неё почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics. Кстати, в методе с rvalue я забыл сказать про то, что в таком методе нужно "очистить" объект. Я не знаю, что такое FlatSprite и как оно "очищается". Если на примере int - ```someInt = 0```.  @FotonPC

Comment: @Bloody.cpp Есть. Но там уже, как по мне, тонкости, которые для *базового* понимания не так существенны...